# Manufacturer of electronic components

Tags: capacitor, resistors, diodes

I've a hobby, dissasembly old household appliances. I found this arrangement and i can'f find its datasheet. Does anyone know who manufactured it? [image]

Answer (score 3):

As clearly printed on the part, it would appear this was made by [TDK](https://www.tdk.com/en/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a hybrid circuit, made by TDK and probably custom for the application.

That kind of construction was kind of a fad with Japanese designers many years ago, just before SMT was widely adopted.